# how to avoid copying in boost range transform

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, boost-range

boost range transform requires `const &` for ranges in arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  using namespace std;

  vector<vector<int>> rt0(10,vector<int>(15,2));
  vector<vector<int>> irt(10,vector<int>(15,5));

  for(auto & i:rt0) {
    for(auto& j:i) cout << j << "  ";
    cout << "\n";
  }
  cout << "\n";
  for(auto & i:irt) {
    for(auto& j:i) cout << j << "  ";
    cout << "\n";
  }

  boost::transform(rt0,irt,rt0.begin(),
    [] (const vector<int> &t0,const vector<int> &it) {
      auto tt = t0;
      boost::transform(t0,it,tt.begin(), plus<int>());
      return tt;
    }
  );
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "\n";
  for(auto & i:rt0) {
    for(auto& j:i) cout << j << "  ";
    cout << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

compile and run with

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cc; ./a.out
```

if `boost::transform`'s `BinaryOperation` took `&` instead of `const &` for `SinglePassRange1` then i wouldn't have needed to create a copy (`auto tt = t0`) and just use `to` instead of `tt`. is there a way to avoid creating this copying (while still using ranges)?

link to boost range transform: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/transform.html

Comment: @AndyProwl , oops i meant `transform` took `&` instead of `const &`. no operation. i'm gonna edit the question

Comment: Could you please post also the declarations of your variables?

Comment: @AndyProwl i edited the question i hope i understood what you meant by variables.

Comment: So the vectors are empty?

Comment: @AndyProwl oops, it's a part of a bigger code. i'll fix it in a bit. they are not empty

Comment: Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? I have the feeling you could use `boost::ref()`, but I can't say for sure until I try it and I can't try it until I get a compilable example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25688/discussion-between-kirill-igum-and-andy-prowl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to use `for_each` either with a tuple or the new boost implementation that takes two arguments.

conceptually `transform` should not modify. it comes from functional programming where there is no in-place modification.